# Using binary search to find k-th largest number in n*m multiplication table

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

So, I am trying to solve the problem: http://codeforces.com/contest/448/problem/D

Bizon the Champion isn't just charming, he also is very smart.

While some of us were learning the multiplication table, Bizon the Champion had fun in his own manner. Bizon the Champion painted an n × m multiplication table, where the element on the intersection of the i-th row and j-th column equals i·j (the rows and columns of the table are numbered starting from 1). Then he was asked: what number in the table is the k-th largest number? Bizon the Champion always answered correctly and immediately. Can you repeat his success?

Consider the given multiplication table. If you write out all n·m numbers from the table in the non-decreasing order, then the k-th number you write out is called the k-th largest number.

Input
The single line contains integers n, m and k (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 5·105; 1 ≤ k ≤ n·m).

Output
Print the k-th largest number in a n × m multiplication table.

What I did was, I applied binary search from 1 to `n*m` looking for the number which has exactly `k` elements less than it. For this, I made the following code:

```
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
ll n,m;
int f (int val);
int min (int a, int b);
int main (void)
{
    int k;
    cin>>n>>m>>k;
    int ind = k;
    ll low = 1LL;
    ll high = n*m;
    int ans;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        ll mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        if (f(mid) == k)
            ans = mid;
        else if (f(mid) < k)
            low = mid+1;
        else
            high = mid-1;
    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
    return 0;

}

int f (int val)
{
    int ret = 0;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        ret = ret + min(val/i,m);
    }
    return ret;
}

int min (int a, int b)
{
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

However, I don't know why but this gives wrong answer on test cases:

```
input
2 2 2
output
2
```

My output comes out to be 0

I am learning binary search but I don't know where am I going wrong with this implementation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this is not about searching, the kth greatest number is the kth element written starting by the end. You can calculate it directly, using modulo and standard operations.

Comment: You need a `break` if you find the answer exactly, otherwise that case would be an infinite loop.  But based on your reported symptom, that isn't the only bug.

Comment: @Dese, but how do you write elements like that? The complexity will be greater than O(n^2) and it won't support the given limits.

Comment: @JSF, even after breaking, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @hans The 1st greatest element is n*m, the second greatest element n*(m-1), the third n*(m-3).... and after you arrive at the beginning of the line: n, then it is (n-1)*m according to the definition. (see the example with the 2 X 3 multiplication table, if you really are talking about greatest elements,then the 4th one is 2: 6 4 3 2 but their definition is about the order of writing so the answer is 3). I am talking about finding a formula so that result = f(n,m,k).

Comment: @Dese is on the right track. The clue is in the word "immediately". A search is never immediate, so the answer must be a calculation whose execution speed is not a function of the values n and m.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the fact that your binary search is not the fastest method, you still want to know why it is incorrect.

First be very clear about what you want and what your f is returning:

> looking for the number which has exactly k elements less than it.

No!  You are looking for the smallest number that has k elements less than **or equal** to it.  And your function `f(X)` returns the count of elements less than or equal to X.

So when f(X) returns a value too small, you know X must be larger by at least 1, so `low=mid+1` is correct.  But when f(X) returns a value too large, X might be perfect (might be an element appearing several times in the table).  Conversely, when f(X) returns exactly the right number, X might still be too big (X might be a value that appears zero times in the table).

So when f(X) is not too small, the best you can do is `high=mid` not `high=mid-1`

```
while (low < high)
{
    ll mid = low + (high-low)/2;
    if (f(mid) < k)
        low = mid+1;
    else
        high = mid;
}
```

Notice low never gets > high, so stop when they are equal, and we don't try to catch the `ans` along the way.  Instead at the end low==high==Answer

The contest says 1 second time limit.  On my computer, your code with that correction solves the max size problem in under a second.  But I'm not sure the judging computer is that fast.

Edit: `int` is too small for the max size of the problem, so you can't return int from f:
n, m, and i each fit in 32 bits, but the input and output of f() as well as k, ret, low and high all need to hold integers up to 2.5e11

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class op {
    static int n,m;
    static long k;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=s.nextInt();
        m=s.nextInt();
        k=s.nextLong();
        long start=1;
        long end=n*m;
        long ans=0;
        while(end>=start){
            long mid=start+end;
            mid/=2;
            long fmid=f(mid);
            long gmid=g(mid);
            if(fmid>=k && fmid-gmid<k){
                ans=mid;
                break;
            }
            else if(f(mid)>k){
                end=mid-1;
            }
            else{
                start=mid+1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ans);

    }
    static long f (long val)
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            ret = ret + Math.min(val/i,m);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    static long g (long val)
    {
        long ret = 0;
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
        {
            if(val%i==0 && val/i<=m){
                ret++;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public static class Pair{
        int x,y;
        Pair(int a,int b){
            x=a;y=b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain you solution. What did the OP did wrong?